# NIntegrate: integrand has evaluated to non numerical values

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have pasted a code that has been giving me some trouble and errors when I try to compute.

> ERROR: "The integrand 1435.1232 E^(-6.4703566*10^6 s^2) deEntrance[s,phi]^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries "

I tried implementing the `?NumericQ` function to ensure the functions are evaluated numerically with no issues but have no success. I've been at it for days, so if anyone can be of any help I would greatly appreciate it!

```
e = 1.60217657*10^-19;
rcgs = 2.8179403267*10^-13;
gamma = 1600/0.511;
n = (10^-10)/e;
lm = 0.549267;
theta = 0.07;
r = lm/theta;
sigmaSbeg = 2.759026*10^-004;
sigmaSend = 2.779847*10^-004;

eta1[phi_] := -(phi^2/(2 r))
eta1prime[phi_] := -((phi*theta)/lm)    
sL[phi_?NumericQ] := (r*phi^3)/24
lambdaBeg[z_] := 1/(sigmaSbeg*Sqrt[2 Pi]) Exp[-(z^2/(2*sigmaSbeg^2))]
lambdaEnd[z_] := 1/(sigmaSend*Sqrt[2 Pi]) Exp[-(z^2/(2*sigmaSend^2))]
lambdaCompress[z_, phi_] := 
     1/((((sigmaSend - sigmaSbeg)/theta)*phi + sigmaSbeg)*Sqrt[2 Pi])
     Exp[-(z^2/(2*(((sigmaSend - sigmaSbeg)/theta)*phi + sigmaSbeg)^2))]

deEntrance[s_, phi_?NumericQ] := With[{sL = sL[phi]}, 
(-((2*n*rcgs*gamma^-1)/(3^(1/3) r^(2/3))))*((lambdaCompress[s - sL, phi] - 
lambdaBeg[s - 4 sL])/sL^(1/3) + NIntegrate[
  (1/(s - sprime)^(1/3)*D[lambdaCompress[sprime, phi], sprime]),{sprime, s - sL, s}])]

deEntranceRMS[x_, phi_] := Sqrt[
NIntegrate[lambdaEnd[s]*(deEntrance[s, phi])^2, {s, -x*sigmaSend, x*sigmaSend}] - 
(NIntegrate[lambdaEnd[s]*(deEntrance[s, phi]), {s,-x*sigmaSend, x*sigmaSend}])^2]

kick1 = NIntegrate[(eta1[phi])*deEntranceRMS[3, phi], {phi, 0.0, lm}]
kick1prime = NIntegrate[(eta1prime[phi])*deEntranceRMS[3, phi], {phi, 0.0, lm}]
```

Comment: you need the `NumericQ` in more places such as `deEntranceRMS`.  Be sure to restart your kernel or `Clear` things when you modify the argument patterns.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's definitly my issue. I tried many places where I thought ?NumericQ should go, but no success. ANy help?

Comment: test evaluate each function that appears explicitly in `NIntegrate` with symbolic arguments. If you get an error add `NumericQ`. ( The one i mentioned in the first comment would be a good place to start.)